# Unable to set content access for specific group in each content type in openatrium

Tags: organic-groups, nodes, distributions

I have installed [openatrium 7.x-2.12](https://www.drupal.org/project/openatrium/releases/7.x-2.12). I have created a private group and added some users to that group.

I tried to create a content page which should be accessed only to the users who belongs to that private group.

But in content page, under group audience, field "your groups" lists option "None" always. I am unable to set my group.

Same problem occurs for event content type also.

Is there any other way to give content access only to group members? It will be helpful for me if any solution is there to solve this.

Please tell me if anybody knows the solution for this. Thanks in advance